# Center views horizontally in iOS stack view

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, messagekit

I'm trying to achieve the following layout (views centered horizontally):

[image]

So I set up a stack view like so:

```
let quickPromptsView: UIStackView = {
    let sv = UIStackView()
    sv.axis = .horizontal
    sv.alignment = .center
    sv.distribution = .equalSpacing
    sv.spacing = 10
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return sv
}()
```

Adding buttons to stack views:

```
func addOptions(options: [DialogNodeOutputOptionsElement]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // clear all subviews
        self.quickPromptsView.subviews.forEach { (view) in
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        for option in options {
            let button = QuickPromptButton()
            button.setTitle(option.label, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTapQuickPrompt), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.quickPromptsView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
    }
}
```

Button class:

```
class QuickPromptButton: UIButton {

    var userFacingValue: String?
    var answerValue: String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.primaryColor.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 15
        setTitleColor(.primaryColor, for: .normal)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This is how I add the stack view, I add it inside another stack part of the [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)

```
func configureQuickPromptsView() {
    view.addSubview(quickPromptsView)
    quickPromptsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    // this stack view belongs to the MessageKit library
    messageInputBar.topStackView.axis = .horizontal
    messageInputBar.topStackView.distribution = .fill
    messageInputBar.topStackView.addArrangedSubview(quickPromptsView)
}
```

However, this is what I get:

[image]

The stack view has 100% the width of the screen. I've tried every single type of `distribution` but that didn't work. I've also tried to insert transparent `UIView`s at the extremes to force the centering but that seems like a hack. Any ideas?

Comment: constraints ??????????

Comment: @Sh_Khan the stack view's job is to manage its arranged views automatically, without having to add additional constraints to the subviews.

Comment: i mean constraints for itself not subviews

Comment: @Sh_Khan what constraints would you add? center horizontally on the stack view?

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the two text bubbles to your stack view?

Comment: @koen updated question

Comment: change `sv.distribution = .fill`

Comment: where and how you add `quickPromptsView` ?

Comment: Is `quickPromptsView` a subview of a vertical stack? That could throw off your alignment.

Comment: `quickPromptsView ` was added to `messageInputBar.topStackView` which is part of the MessageKit pod

Comment: That seems pretty essential info which would have saved a lot of guessing. And what happened to your picture, now they are both on the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just center your stack view horizontally in its superview.

*Examples below are using [UIKitPlus](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus) library (it is pure UIKit but declarative and support LivePreview, iOS9+)*

```swift
UView {
    UHStack {
        UView {
            UText("Yes")
                .color(.green)
                .edgesToSuperview(h: 8, v: 4)
        }
        .border(1, .green)
        .circle()
        UView {
            UText("No")
                .color(.red)
                .edgesToSuperview(h: 8, v: 4)
        }
        .border(1, .red)
        .circle()
        UView {
            UText("I don't know")
                .color(.darkGray)
                .edgesToSuperview(h: 8, v: 4)
        }
        .border(1, .darkGray)
        .circle()
    }
    .alignment(.center)
    .distribution(.equalSpacing)
    .spacing(10)
    .edgesToSuperview(v: 0)
    .centerXInSuperview() // this will center your stack view
}
.edgesToSuperview(h: 0)
.centerYInSuperview()
```

[image: First solution]

Or use a little hack by adding two views with equal width, one in the beginning of stack and one as the last view in stack.

```swift
let v1 = UView()
UHStack {
    v1
    UView {
        UText("Yes")
            .color(.green)
            .edgesToSuperview(h: 8, v: 4)
    }
    .border(1, .green)
    .circle()
    UView {
        UText("No")
            .color(.red)
            .edgesToSuperview(h: 8, v: 4)
    }
    .border(1, .red)
    .circle()
    UView {
        UText("I don't know")
            .color(.darkGray)
            .edgesToSuperview(h: 8, v: 4)
    }
    .border(1, .darkGray)
    .circle()
    UView().width(to: v1)
}
.alignment(.center)
.spacing(10)
.edgesToSuperview(h: 0)
.centerYInSuperview()
```

[image: Second solution]

The stack view itself can't center inner views automatically unfortunately, so you have to help it to do that.

Comment: this question for uikit not swiftui

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I don't think centering horizontally is an option here because I'm using a stack view which is built into a library (MessageKit) and don't want to touch the constraints there. Using two views as a hack sounds ok, however, I'm not sure how to go about doing that in UIKit without third party libraries

Comment: @Cesare Equal width is a native thing, just set width constraint of first view to width of second view and that's it. Programmatically you can use `widthAnchor`  property of UIView to set it :)

Comment: @Sh_Khan this answer is written in pure UIKit and works since iOS9

Comment: I'll accept and add – if you're using a third-party library such as MessageKit you can add a container view `UIView` to the pre-built stack view which will hold  _another_ stack view, but this time you decide the constraints (such as center horizontally). (Not sure if this made sense but here ya go)

Comment: I'd recommend you to avoid `MessageKit` usage and write your chat window by yourself since it is very easy. Check UIKitPlus example app. But since you're using it I think that there is nothing bad to add in their container view your UIView with your centered StackView inside :)